# What could be the reason why webpack outputs these logs

Tags: express, webpack

I have a webpack configuration for express app like so:

```
module.exports = {
  mode,
  entry,
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: outputPath,
    filename: 'main.js'
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    exprContextCritical: false,
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: [
          'ts-loader',
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  watch: mode === 'development',
}
```

[image]

Although when I comment out the express() call and run the build again. They all disappear.
What could be the reason this is happening and how could one go about resolving these issues.

Using webpack 5.82.1

Comment: what seems to be the problem?